# How to create two rows at the same time by grouping two specific values as a set

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a data_type table and a data table. The column structure is as follows.

```
data_type    data
=========    ====================
id | type    type_ID | count
---------    --------------------
 1 | a             1 | 50
 2 | b             2 | 100
 3 | c             3 | 30
```

In data_type, types 'a' and 'b' are sets, and they must be added to the data table at the same time, and only one of them cannot be entered.

For example

```
INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50), (2,90) <- O

INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50), (3,100) <- X
INSERT INTO data (typeId, count)
VALUES (1,50) <- X
```

Is there any way to do this with SQL rather than ORM?
I need help.

Below is my current query.
DAO.js

```
const createData = async(userId, a1, a2, typeId, count) => {
  await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO a (user_id, a1, a2)
  VALUES(?,?,?)`,
    [user_id, a1, a2]
  );

  const typeAndCount = typeId
    .map((type, index) => `((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()),${type},${count[index]})`)
    .join(",");

  const data = await myDataSource.query(
    `INSERT INTO data (a_id ,type_id, count)
  VALUES ${typeAndCount}`
  );
  return data;
};
```

Comment: This looks familiar, but not really any better asked

Comment: I've edited the question a bit.